# Plotting data by color variable with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, colors

This is something of an extension of a previous question here:

[Assign colors to a data frame based on shared values with a character string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42457149/assign-colors-to-a-data-frame-based-on-shared-values-with-a-character-string-in/42457706#42457706)

I now have a data frame with `x`, `y`, `errrs`, and `newcolors` and I want to plot the data and error bars by color using ggplot2.  I've tried this, and the plot works well, but the colors are not even close to being correct.  I've tried defining the color variables in different places within the `ggplot()` call, but no luck.  What am I missing?

Here is the data:

```
names          <- c( "TC3", "102", "172", "136", "142", "143", "AC2G" )
colors         <- c( "darkorange", "forestgreen", "darkolivegreen", "darkgreen", "darksalmon", "firebrick3", "firebrick1" )
dataA          <- c( "JR13-101A", "TC3B", "JR12-136C", "AC2GA", "TC3A" )
newcolors      <- rep( NA, length( dataA ) )
dataA          <- as.data.frame( cbind( dataA, newcolors ) )
x              <- c( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 )
y              <- c( 10, 6, 3, 18, 2 )
errs           <- c( 2, 1, 2, 1, 2 )

dataA          <- cbind( dataA, x, y, errs )
```

and a solution to my previous question by @Dave2e that assigns colors by sample name:

```
dataA$newcolors <- as.character( dataA$newcolors )
 for( j in 1:length( names ) ) {
  dataA$newcolors[ grep( names[ j ], dataA$dataA ) ] <- colors[ j ] 
}
```

and finally the plotting code I've tried:

```
ggplot( dataA, aes( x = x, y = y) ) +
  geom_errorbar( aes( ymin = y - errs, ymax = y + errs, color = newcolors ), 
                 width = 0.03 ) + 
  geom_point( size = 5, aes( color = newcolors) )
```

(I've also tried putting the colors into the `aes()` call up front by `aes( x = x, y = y, color = newcolors`).  The plot looks good, apart from the fact that the colors are not correct.  `"darkorange"` shows up as a light green  `"darkgreen"` is some pinkish color, and `"firebrick1"` is a light blue.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but wouldn't it be easier to change the colors afterwards using `scale_color_manual` ?

Comment: Best to use `scale_colour_manual` or use `colour = I(newColours)` in the aes to use the colours as colours

Comment: Ahh, you are right @Richard Telford... Don't know how I missed the `I(newcolors)` tool.  Thanks for clearing it up for me.

Comment: I don't quite understand how to use `scale_color_manual` to plot these, and the `I(newcolors)` call plots solid symbols, as opposed to symbols with a black border.  How would I define these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458412/plotting-data-by-color-variable-with-ggplot2-in-r#comment72062654_42458412) of the OP, you may try

```
ggplot(dataA, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = I(newcolors))) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = y - errs, ymax = y + errs), 
                 width = 0.03) + 
  geom_point(size = 5, shape = 21)
```

[image]

In `geom_point()` size, shape and border color have been explicitely defined, i.e., outside of a call to `aes()`. Shapes numbered 21 to 24 are filled (see http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_shape.html for available shapes). Consequently, the `fill` aesthetic but not the `color` aesthetic has been defined in the call to `aes()`. So, error bars and symbol borders are printed in black by default.

The advantage (or drawback, perhaps) is that the data point which had been assigned `NA` as `newcolor` is visible.

**For comparison**, below is how the plot looked after picking up the suggestion from [Richard Telford's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458412/plotting-data-by-color-variable-with-ggplot2-in-r/42466628#comment72059829_42458412):

```
ggplot(dataA, aes(x = x, y = y, color = I(newcolors))) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = y - errs, ymax = y + errs), 
                width = 0.03) + 
  geom_point(size = 5)
```

[image]

Note that the leftmost data point was removed by `ggplot2` as there was no color, i.e., `NA`, assigned to this data point.

> Warning message:
>   Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).